# DisplayActionSheet throws exception only in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin

DisplayActionSheet throw me in catch block with Exception null only in Ios

```
  private string signType = string.Empty;

signType = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(SystemMessages.PhotoSaveFolder, "Cancel",
                null, SystemMessages.InstallationPhoto, SystemMessages.SerialNumbers);
```

there is no issue in android.

Can anybody know what can cause this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exception is thrown?

Comment: in catch block i get  Exeption ex =null

Comment: mmm, maybe you can try removing try statement and let the exception bubble until the app close and review the Debug section in the Output window.

Comment: @JesusAngulo tried so too.in that case it will not generate any bubble exception.it just dont do on button click..not open displayaction

Comment: does Output show anything?

Comment: In output window getting below "Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fb600ef2810> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PhoneMasterDetailRenderer: 0x7fb600d41c90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. it is because i was trying to open displayactionsheet from page2 which is redirected from page1. and after navigation i removed page 1 from stack.so it causing this problem.

Thank you all for your valuable  time and Help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below sample code

```
private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        str = await DisplayActionSheet("Title", "Cancel",
                        null, "Action1", "Action2");
    }
}
```

And use it on any button clicked event

```
btn.Clicked += Btn_Clicked;
```

Or you can create any simple method and call it. This works for me.

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati From Where are you exactly doing that? and it might also be possible that, the mainpage object is not ready(not initialized) when you are trying to do that.

Comment: ya i got issue..from 1 page i open another one.and remove first page from stack.and from second page i was trying to open this.so it was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will work for you

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
  {
    string str = string.Empty;
    str = await DisplayActionSheet("Title", "Cancel",
                    null, "Action1", "Action2");
   });
```